# Akka http add header to POST request with body

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka, akka-http, akka-testkit

I have an akka http route that accepts a json in the body of the request. I am trying to test that route by using akka http test kit.

```
val header = RawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
Post("/tasks", trigger.asJson.noSpaces) ~> addHeader(header) ~>
    addCredentials(OAuth2BearerToken(VALID_TOKEN)) ~> Route.seal(route) ~> check {
    status shouldBe StatusCodes.OK
  }
```

This test is failing with message

```
415 Unsupported Media Type was not equal to 200 OK
```

How do i properly add the content type header to the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let akka-http create `RequestEntity` on its own instead of passing json as `String` yourself.

You just need to pass `trigger` as the second parameter of `Post.apply` as is.

```
Post("/tasks", trigger) ~> addCredentials(OAuth2BearerToken(VALID_TOKEN)) ~> Route.seal(route) ~> check {
  status shouldBe StatusCodes.OK
}
```

This will require a `ToEntityMarshaller[Trigger]` available in your implicit context.

And you can add it in the same way as you do in you route definition by importing/extending `de.heikoseeberger.akkahttpargonaut.ArgonautSupport` and argonaut `CodecJson[Trigger]` if you use argonaut for example.

In case you want to pass arbitrary string value, do

```
Post("/tasks").withEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, someJsonAsString) ~> addCredentials(OAuth2BearerToken(VALID_TOKEN)) ~> Route.seal(route) ~> check {
   status shouldBe StatusCodes.OK
}
```

Comment: This works but it will always send the request body with a proper json. I want to test the case where the json is invalid as well.